# How to update datagridview if I add new row to existing rows in C#?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, sql-server-2012, newrow

In my program which has datagridview for insert,update or delete Purchase Order and it behave like as a shopping cart.This datagridview consist of BookName,ISBNNo,Order quantity,unit price and total.When I insert this datagridview data to database,each row insert with unique id PO_Cart_No(pk) which has identity value.

And also other background textbox details which are Po_No,supplier_Id and Grand total details insert into separate table which called PO table.And also this two tables link with foreign key PO_No.My question is when I add new row to existing row to update database,that new row didn't insert and other row data has updated.
Where is the problem.This is my code for you,

```
public void UpdatePurchseOrderTable(int PO_No,int Supplier_ID, string Date, string RequiredDate, double GrandTotal)
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        con.mysqlconnection();
        string query = "UPDATE TBL_PO "
            + " SET Supplier_ID = @Supplier_ID,Date = @Date,"
            + "RequiredDate = @RequiredDate,GrandTotal=@GrandTotal"
             + " WHERE PO_No = @PO_No";
        con.sqlquery(query);
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PO_No", SqlDbType.Int));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@PO_No"].Value = PO_No;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Supplier_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@Supplier_ID"].Value = Supplier_ID;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.Date));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = Date;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequiredDate", SqlDbType.Date));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@RequiredDate"].Value = RequiredDate;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GrandTotal", SqlDbType.Money));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@GrandTotal"].Value = GrandTotal;
        con.nonquery();
    }

    public void UpdatePOCartTable(int PO_No,string ISBN_No,int OrderQuantity, double UnitPrice, double Total)
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        con.mysqlconnection();
        string query = "UPDATE TBL_PO_Cart"
            + " SET ISBN_No = @ISBN_No, OrderQuantity= @OrderQuantity,"
            + "UnitPrice= @UnitPrice,Total=@Total"
            + " WHERE PO_No = @PO_No";
        con.sqlquery(query);
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PO_No", SqlDbType.Int));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@PO_No"].Value = PO_No;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ISBN_No", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@ISBN_No"].Value = ISBN_No;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OrderQuantity", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@OrderQuantity"].Value = OrderQuantity;
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.Money));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@UnitPrice"].Value = Math.Round(UnitPrice,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Total", SqlDbType.Money));
        con.cmd.Parameters["@Total"].Value = Math.Round(Total,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        con.nonquery();
    }
```

and PO form data as follows

```
 private void btnedit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        try
        {
            if (txtPONo.Text != "" || cmbsupID.Text != "" || date1.Text != "" || requireddate.Text != "" || txtgrandTotal.Text != "")
            {
                PurchaseOrder PO = new PurchaseOrder();
                if (cmbsupID.Text.Contains('-'))
                {
                    string str = cmbsupID.Text;
                    int index = str.IndexOf('-');
                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        int value = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, index));
                        PO.UpdatePurchseOrderTable(Convert.ToInt32(txtPONo.Text), value, date1.Text, requireddate.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtgrandTotal.Text));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmbsupID.Text);
                    PO.UpdatePurchseOrderTable(Convert.ToInt32(txtPONo.Text), value2, date1.Text, requireddate.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtgrandTotal.Text));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    int PONO = Convert.ToInt32(txtPONo.Text);
                    string column1 = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    int column2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    double column3= Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    double column4 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                    PO.UpdatePOCartTable(PONO,column1,column2,column3,column4);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            ClearData();
            retviewPO_No();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use an Insert command to add a row to a database table. Add the record to the main order table first; then add a `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();` after the Insert command. This will return the PK of the last inserted record which you can use for the foreign keys in the other tables.

Comment: Please can you suggest me an answer?

Comment: I am not sure what your DynamicConnection class is doing. I could only provide straight ADO.net. Have you tried what I suggested in my comment?